# Polyfill Number.isInteger, Array.from, Set in Tableau Web Data Connector

Tags: set, typeerror, tableau-api, referenceerror

I have following Problems when attaching a library to connect to via the Tableau Web Data Connector. I get the following errors and wanted to know which polyfills or other solutions can bypass this errors:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Number.isInteger file: URL line xxxx
>
> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set file: URL line xxxx
>
> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Array.from(xxx)' file: URL line: xxxx

The Tableau Web Data Connector uses an old QT Webkit Browser in Version 5.4 and does not support ES6 or higher.

Any informations regarding this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of babel-polyfill was the answer for my problems.